# Different navigation bars based on user selection

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to have different navigation bars ?
I want that the user have the opportunity to choose between navigation bars.

**Eg :** 3 navigation bars (only the colors of the navigation bar is modified).

Couldn't find anything that fit.

Comment: yes you  change navigation bar color

Comment: Do you mind reading the `UINavigationBar` class reference?

Comment: You can do that if user is selecting any of the colour then keep the flag for each colour. Suppose you have three colour the red,blue,white.Then keep flag for the colour as 0,1,2. If user selects the white colour then change the navigation bar colour to white and store the flag in local db. Whenever user open the app ypu first check the flag and according to that set the colour of navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always change the color of your Navigation Bar. Simply allow user to select the color (he/she wants) and store it in some part of your Application. You can also allow the user to set the Color using RGB Values. You have to just create the color from RGB Values. Like this :

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(45/255.0) green:(55/255.0) blue:(55/255.0) alpha:1];
```

Then you can modify your Navigation Bar using that color with this Code :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = myColor;
```

---

**Update for iOS 7 :** One should use `barTintColor` instead of `tintColor`.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = myColor;
```

Comment: I run the app under iOS7 so I must call self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = myColor;   Problem solved. Thank you very much.